# Client side validations gem not working if I fetch form via ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, client-side-validation

If I fetch a simple_form using ajax request, client side validations gem doesn't work..

```
<%= link_to 'Add +', new_group_path, :remote => true, :id => "new_group_link" %>
```

Now the form new group will show up and its not triggering client side validations.

I got the issue that client side functions are not binding with the form. (The functions specified in javascript assets.)

But how I to trigger those functions.??

**EDIT**

Think about standard scaffold form. So as per the link_to tag specified above. new_group_path will go the new action and using respond_to block, new.js.erb file will be rendered. Right. Here is the code in new.js.erb

```
  $('#new_group_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

Comment: can you provide more code ? Are your assets have document.onready bindings ?

Comment: As I understand, you fetched the form via ajax request, and it not got onsubmit and other handlers, which should to check the form ? show the js code wich fetches form.

Comment: This is not js :) it is template.

Comment: @MohitJain does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you get a form with ajax you should enable client side validation by yourself. Here is the [link](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#enabling-disabling-and-resetting-on-the-client):

```
$(new_form).enableClientSideValidations();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the client side validations to trigger for all forms loaded via ajax, use this somewhere in your main.js:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    if($('form[data-validate]').length){
        $('form[data-validate]').enableClientSideValidations();
    }
});
```

Of course, you should have `:validate => true` in the form for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

**From the docs found this:**

---

In your Gemfile add the following:

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

`Order matters here.` `SimpleForm` and `ClientSideValidations`

need to be 
`required before ClientSideValidations-SimpleForm`.

---

In your FormBuilder you only need to enable validations:

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
```

That should be enough to get you going.

By default the validators will be serialized and embedded in a `<script>` tag following the  tag. If you would like to render that `<script>` tag elsewhere you can do this by passing a name to `:validate`

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => :user_validators do |f| %>
```

---

If you have rendered a new form via AJAX into your page you will need to enable that form for validation:

```
$(new_form).enableClientSideValidations();
```

You should attach this to an event that is fired when the new HTML renders.

You can use the same function if you introduce new inputs to an existing form:

```
$(new_input).enableClientSideValidations();
```